# not able to override scorePayload function in ClassicSimilarity in elasticsearch similarity implementation

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to implement similarity in Elasticsearch. I want to use payloads for score calculations along with TF and IDF values. When I check the ClassicSimilarity documentation(https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/ClassicSimilarity.html), there exits a scorePayload function, which can be overloaded. While, when I am extending the ClassicSimilarity class, it is showing an error on the scorePayload function. I checked the imported class as well, and there does not exist a payload function.
What am I doing wrong in this?

```
package org.elasticsearch.index.similarity;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.payloads.PayloadHelper;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.ClassicSimilarity;
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;

public class CustomTFIDFScorer extends ClassicSimilarity{

    @Override
    protected float scorePayload(int doc, int start, int end, BytesRef payload) {

        if (payload != null) {
            return PayloadHelper.decodeFloat(payload.bytes, payload.offset);
            } 
        else {
            return 1.0F;
            }
      }

    @Override
      public float tf(float freq) {
        return freq;
      }

    @Override
      public float idf(long docFreq, long docCount) {
        return (float)(Math.log((docCount+1)/(double)(docFreq+1)) + 1.0);
      }

    @Override
    public float lengthNorm(int length) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and this is my maven file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>CustomPayloadSimilarity</groupId>
  <artifactId>ElasticseachCustomSimilarity</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>

  <dependencies>  
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: can you post error message here , that would generate more interest in answering this question.

Comment: The above code is showing this error while compiling, "The method scorePayload(int, int, int, BytesRef) of type CustomTFIDFScorer must override a superclass 
 method".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic 7.4 [uses Lucene 8.2](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-7-4-0-released) where method you are trying to [override](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_2_0//core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/ClassicSimilarity.html) does not exists

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on how I can use payloads for scoring in implementing the similarity module?

Comment: I have to look that up - but BM25Similarity , which is current default got an method matching to the one you are trying to override..